# Translate local url address to full url

Tags: macos, vpn, redirection, macos-sierra

I have a configured `VPN` that let's me work from home, but I can not access the remote tools as I do when I am at work, example:

At work I can type to a browser:

```
jenkins/
```

from home I have to add an extension to the domain name:

```
jenkins.local.private
```

Is there a way to make the first one work from home too? knowing that this is just an example, I want a general solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a OS X/macOS system, you can take the following steps to [modify the search domain settings](http://support.moonpoint.com/os/os-x/domain-search/) to have the system automatically access x.local.private if you type http://x or https://x in your browser's address bar:

1. Click on the Apple icon at the top, left-hand side of your screen.
2. Choose **System Preferences** then **Network**.
3. Select the relevant network service, such as Wi-Fi or Ethernet, then click on the **Advanced** button.
4. Click on **DNS**.
5. Click in the **Search Domains** box and then click on the "+" at the bottom of that box to add a new search domain.
6. Type the name of the search domain, e.g. `local.private`.
7. Click on **OK**

You can add multiple domains; domains will be searched in the order you list them with the search starting at the topmost entry and continuing down through the list of domains with the search stopping when a valid name is found.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, add the suffix to your DNS search domains in your DNS settings in the Network panel of System Preferences.